# Json array as json object is not passed properly to controller in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following javascript method to pass json object with some object and an arry to my controller. Json objects are assigned properly but array is empty what am I doing worn.

```
 function setData() {
var quotation = {
    ID : 0,
    Number : "",
    AccountName : getAccount(),
    CurrencyID : getCurrencyID(),
    Date: getQuoteDate(),
    ExchangeRate :getExchangeRate(),
    Percentage : getPercentage(),
    PriceListId: getPriceListId(),
}
quotation.Items = [];
$.each(this.selectedItem.items, function (index, qitem) {
    var Item = {
        ID: 1,
        ItemNumber:"lcfe"
    };
    quotation.Items.push(Item);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateQuotation", "Main")',
        data: quotation,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (dat1a) {

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            alert("Status: " + XMLHttpRequest); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

My Model classes.

```
  public class Quotation
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public List<QuotationItem> Items { get; set; }
    //....
}
 public class QuotationItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

   public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is result I seen in debug.

[image]

I can see 2 objects are added in List but their vlaues ID, ItemNumber are not assigned?

Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked the data that you are sending before it is sent??

Comment: You will need to stringify the data - `data: JSON.stringify(quotation)`

Comment: No need @StephenMuecke. jQuery converts it if it's not a string already (according to the docs).

Comment: @Andy, Would be needed because of the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, but just realized that its a GET, not a POST. So this will not work anyway - the collection items need indexers.

Comment: Because its a GET the data is sent as query string values so the collection property/values need to be sent as `Items[0].ID=1, Items[1].ID=2` etc

Comment: yes, I was wrong. it should be post not get. so I made it post and JSON.stringify(qoutation) object and all data is there. Thanks all